# problem with online preview latex

Tags: preview

[image]

Hello,
everything was fine with my projects on Latex online, until today. The only difference  I made is to add New command, after that I receive the following preview for all my previous projects, which I know were ok before. Can someone help?

Comment: you will have an undefined command error from `\stackMath` as you have not defined it. It is not a standard command you presumably intended to load some package?, and you get an error from the mis-used `\\ ` on line 14  `\\ ` should be very rarely used but if it is used it _ends_ a line not starts one.

Comment: the pdf preview seems unrelated to the errors, looks like you have crashed pdf.js somehow, try restarting your browser

Comment: thank you everyone, it was my browser problem. Should i delete the question?

Comment: not necessarily, other people may see same: you could self answer saying a browser re-start fixed it (but you should also fix those tex errors!!)